# How to write to a file in tinyscheme?

Tags: lisp, scheme

Scheme implementation : tinyscheme

Here is my try:

```
(with-output-to-file "biophilia.c"
  (lambda (output-port)
    (write "Hello" output-port)))
```

Ceates biophilia.c with following content:

**Error: ( : 26) not enough arguments**

What am I doing wrong here? how to repair it?

```
(define (with-output-to-file s p)
     (let ((outport (open-output-file s)))
          (if (eq? outport #f)
               #f
               (let ((prev-outport (current-output-port)))
                    (set-output-port outport)
                    (let ((res (p)))
                         (close-output-port outport)
                         (set-output-port prev-outport)
                         res)))))
```

Comment: Come on, man, the function called and the function defined have different names!

Comment: @leppie ok, retwitted %D I want to try to exchange lua on my arm with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `with-output-to-file` incorrectly.

The second argument is a thunk, and not a procedure expecting a port argument.

So call it like:

```
(with-output-to-file "biophilia.c"
  (lambda ()
    (write "Hello")))
```

`with-output-to-file` already does the re-binding of the current-port for you (as you tried in your reconstruction).

See the Racket docs for it [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/file-ports.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._with-output-to-file%29%29).

Comment: segmentation fault :) but it works, it writes to file then segfaults :(

Comment: @Sholy: Try another Scheme. The code should work. I really suspect TinyScheme is at fault here.

Comment: Which one, I need light embedded one for arm. Tiny was the most notable one I discovered.

Comment: @Sholy: You can try Gambit. If on Android, you can try Kawa.

Comment: @Sholy: It could also be due to writing to location where you have no permission to write.

Comment: it writes file, writes it wrong, because I need evalute what I write (I mean translate things alike \n\r to newline) (I will open new question fro it) and then it fails with segfault :P

Comment: You might also look at Chibi scheme, which is designed for embedding.