# how to write alike display (printf) to file in scheme?

Tags: lisp, scheme

Using TinyScheme.

I'm writing my code to file (solved it in 50% here: [How to write to a file in tinyscheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908660/how-to-write-to-file/10908879#comment14225320_10908879)) with:

```
(with-output-to-file "biophilia.c"
  (lambda ()
    (write code)
    ))
; and segmentation fault comes here
```

but it writes my code with "" qotes and \n\r as is so it doesn't translate it to newline.

I need to write code like it looks with `(display code)`

in example in [racket docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/file-ports.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._with-output-to-file%29%29) there is printf but seems like TinyScheme implementation got no printf, maybe I need to discover (add code of it) printf?

Comment: Why dont you just use `display`? Failing that, `printf` is a small piece of code. Example in TSPL3 IIRC.

Comment: display displays, not to file.

Comment: `display` should also write to the output-file. Like `write` does.

Comment: but it doesn't I can't understand why it adds "Error: ( : 25) not enough arguments"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution, the only fix is ex-hanged put-char to write-char

```
  (define assert
    (lambda (aa msg)
      (if (null? aa)
    #t
    (if (not (car aa))
      (error msg)
      (assert (cdr aa) msg))))) 

 (display "define fprintf\n\r")
(define (fprintf port f . args)
   (let ((len (string-length f)))
     (let loop ((i 0) (args args))
       (cond ((= i len) (assert (null? args)))
         ((and (char=? (string-ref f i) #\~)
           (< (+ i 1) len))
          (dispatch-format (string-ref f (+ i 1)) port (car args))
          (loop (+ i 2) (cdr args)))
         (else
          (write-char (string-ref f i) port)
          (loop (+ i 1) args))))))

(display "define printf\n\r")
(define (printf f . args)
   (let ((port (current-output-port)))
     (apply fprintf port f args)
     (flush-output-port port)))

    (display "writing to output file biophilia.c\n\r")
    (with-output-to-file "biophilia.c"
      (lambda ()
        (printf code)
        ))
```

code doesn't segfault anymore

but in the end of file: Error: ( : 25) not enough arguments

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
(call-with-output-file "biophilia.c" 
    (lambda (port) 
        (write-string code port)))
```

Provided "code" is a string. It will remove any escapes, and write it as plain text.